# ZF2 Resultset with Combine

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm having troubles with getting results from a "Combine" object since it is not a "Select" object anymore.

I need to `UNION` 4 Select objects and this only works with the Combine class of `Zend Framework` since the `combine()` method of the Select class only supports to union two select objects.

I could get the sql string and then get the resultset but for what am I building up a sql in zf2 style when I need to convert it back into a string again to fetch results?

I also want to put all those unioned selects into one select like

```
(new Sql($adapter))->select()->from(['x' => $combinedSelects]);
```

But then it says

> "Object of class Zend\Db\Sql\Combine could not be converted to string"

Any ideas?

Edit:

For better understanding of the problem i got:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select1 = ...
$select2 = ...
$select3 = ...

$combine = new Combine([
    $select1,
    $select2,
    $select3
]);

$combinedSelects = $combine->union($select)
```

Thats where my problem starts:
Now i make:

```
$sql = $combinedSelects->getSqlString($platform);
```

to get the sql string and then put it into a new variable like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( $sql ) AS x";
```

But i want it like mentioned above:

```
$sql = (new Sql($adapter))->select()->from(['x' => $combinedSelects]);
```

so that I can use:

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($sql);
```

and not:

```
$resultSet = $adapter->query($sql, []);
```

Hope this helps more to identify my problem

Comment: why you do not use `join`  ? I think your problem could solve with join and combine ..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i think a join is not really an option here, i edited my post so that you may know more what my real problem is